# Only arrows with names fly straight

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does anyone know how to make only named arrows fly without an arc in Minecraft? I have the command: `execute as @e[type=arrow] run data merge @s {NoGravity:1b}` working great, but I'm trying to make only certain arrows shoot this way.

I have tried naming my arrows "bullets" and then trying something like: `execute as @e[type=arrow,name=bullets] run data merge @s {NoGravity:1b}`, but this does not work. Neither does using the NBT tags for the arrow (as far as I can tell, I might be doing it wrong).

Is there a way to make only arrows named "bullets" fly straight?

Answer (score 1):

There are two NBT tags that transfer from arrows (the item) to arrows (the entity) that I know of. Those are `CustomPotionColor` and `CustomPotionEffects`.

Given the item `tipped_arrow{CustomPotionColor:nb}`, once fired it becomes `@e[type=arrow,nbt={Color:nb}`

Given the item `tipped_arrow{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:nb,Amplifier:xb,Duration:999999,ShowParticles:0b}]}`, once fired it becomes `@e[type=arrow,nbt={CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:nb,Amplifier:xb}]}]`